# Script for getting memory information

Tags: linux, perl, unix

```
 #! usr/bin/perl
    sub memoryInfo
    {
        print "Inside memory info \n";
        @memoryInfo = qx(free -m);
        foreach (@memoryInfo)
        {
            print "$_\n";
        }

    }

    &memoryInfo;
```

This is my Perl program which is not working. i need some information like total memory, total physical memory , total used memory , total cache memory , total swap memory and total used swap memory.

Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Perl path is wrong. Missing `/`. Correct it to #!/usr/bin/perl

Comment: Please don't use `&` in sub calls; the modern way to call a sub is just `memoryInfo` or `memoryInfo()`.

Comment: Also, whenever you post a question, please explain exactly how it is "not working".  What does that mean: doesn't compile?  Runs but doesn't do what you expect?  etc.

Comment: Added that but i cant get output.

Comment: Now i have done this : #!/usr/bin/perl
sub memoryInfo
{
    print "Inside memory info \n";
    my $val = `free -m`;
    print "$val";
}

memoryInfo;

Comment: but i get output as "Inside memory info" and nothing else :(

Comment: it give me -1. What does that means?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub memoryInfo
{
    print "Inside memory info \n";
    my @memoryInfo = qx(free -m);
    foreach (@memoryInfo)
    {
        print "$_\n";
    }

}

memoryInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks man but i get error : Inside memory info 
Can't exec "free": No such file or directory at variables.pl line 9.

Comment: Thank you :) its running now

Answer (score 1):

your program is running fine, provided you call it with

```
perl meminfo.pl
```

when made executable you should get an error like:

```
./meminfo.pl
bash: ./meminfo.pl: usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

which indicates your `shebang` (the first line starting with `#!` is wrong...

also, you'll notice extra newlines in your output, because every line in your array already has a newline from itself...

finally:

- use strict and warnings
- don't call subs with `&`
- avoid camel case in variables

a working version of your program could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub memoryInfo {
    print "Inside memory info \n";

    my @memoryinfo = qx(free -m);
    chomp @memoryinfo;

    foreach (@memoryinfo) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

memoryInfo;
```

Comment: I get error : Any idea why? bash-3.2# perl variables.pl
Inside memory info 
Can't exec "free": No such file or directory at variables.pl line 9.

Comment: this error has nothing to do with Perl. you don't have `free` installed or in your `PATH`. Either install it, change your `PATH` or use the full name including directory...

Comment: Now it is running , thanks a lot :)